# Error when Update-Database using Code-First: "There is already an object named 'something' in the database."

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2012, ef-code-first

I'm doing database migration using Code-First in Visual Studio 2015. Along the way, i've done the migration steps up till Add-Migration .

After Add-Migration, i've added this line of code

```
Database.SetInitializer(New MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion(Of DbContext1, Migrations.Configuration))
```

in my DbContext constructor to set up Database Initializer since i missed this step previously. After that, i executed

```
"Add-Migration initial -Force"
```

in the Package Manager Console because i fear that this part is needed in the Add-Migration process. Then, i directly executed

```
"Update-Database"
```

The problem is after i did this, an error comes out

> This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection.

**ADDED**

After i restarted my computer, the above error didn't come out anymore when i executed 'Update-Database'. Instead, another error came out:

> There is already an object named 'something' in the database.

I saw an answer thread suggesting to execute

```
Add-Migration Initial -IgnoreChanges
```

followed by

```
Update-Database -verbose
```

I've tried both but it still shows the same error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To be able to fix your problems you should understand how EF deals with connection strings and how migrations work.

**How EF deals with connection strings**: Usually your `DbContext` has a parameterless constructor, which calls its base class constructor with a hard-coded connection string name. Your project `app.config` or `web.config` file should contain a `connectionStrings` section which defines a connection string with that name. **This is the default connection string used in your project** when you don't explicitly provide a connection string parameter to the Package Manager Console commands.

Some example code with a connection string name `MyConnectionStringName`:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext() : base("MyConnectionStringName") { ... }
    ...
}
```

And in your `.config` file:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionStringName" connectionString="..." />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

If you don't use that approach you still can manually provide the right connection string as a parameter to `Update-Database` in the Package Manager Console like this:

```
Update-Database -ConnectionString <your connection string here> -ConnectionProviderName System.Data.SqlClient
```

You can also use any connection string name that you have defined in your `.config` file:

```
Update-Database -ConnectionStringName MyConnectionStringName
```

And now about **how migrations work**: Migrations are code files. Every time you run `Add-Migration` a code file is generated/updated, usually in a folder called `Migrations` inside your project. The name of a migration file is composed with a timestamp of its generation concatenated with the name used when running `Add-Migration`. You can check the contents of those files and see the effects of running `Add-Migration`. You can also modify them once generated, and add your own code, though you should not need to do that by the moment.

Migrations are intended to be incremental. You start with an `Initial` migration, and every time you change your model code you generate a new migration file. The database contains a table named `__MigrationsHistory` that keeps trace of which migrations have been run in your database.

Every single migration has a method `Up` and a method `Down`. When you run `Update-Database` there are always two implicit parameters: `SourceMigration` and `TargetMigration`. EF incrementally applies the `Up` methods of all the migrations between `SourceMigration` and `TargetMigration` (or the `Down` methods if you are downgrading your database). The default scenario when you don't specify the `SourceMigration` and `TargetMigration` parameters is that `SourceMigration` is the last migration applied to the database and `TargetMigration` is the last of the pending ones. EF determines those parameters by querying the `__MigrationsHistory` table of the default database of your project, so if that database is not in a consistent state your migrations can be generated incorrectly. I think this is what is causing your problems.

So every time you run `Update-Database` EF looks into the `__MigrationsHistory` table to know which migrations must be run, depending on the state of your database, and after executing the SQL of the migrations a new record is inserted in that table for each applied migration.

It seems that at some point your database `__MigrationsHistory` contents got messed up. It happens when running `Update-Database` and `Add-Migrations` without following the right order and using the `-force` parameter.

**My advice to fix your problems**: Start from scratch: delete your database, delete your migration files, generate a new clean `Initial` migration with `Add-Migration Initial`, run it only once with `Update-Database`. From that point on, every time you change your model code you generate a new incremental migration with `Add Migration YourNewMigrationName`, using different names each time, and apply the new migration by running `Update-Database` once.

Note: Instead of the incremental migrations, if you have a good enough knowledge about how migrations work you can also use only one `Initial` migration and update it whenever your model code changes, by executing `Add-Migrations Initial -force`. The `-force` parameter makes sure that instead of generating a new migration file your existing `Initial` migration file will be overwritten. This approach comes handy at development phase, but in production usually it is not a good approach, as you probably want to run your database updates incrementally every time you deploy a new version of your code (you will probably not be able to drop your database and create it again, and also you will need to maintain your data and make sure you don't have data loss when updating your database).

Migrations are code files which are generated by EF to create and update your database. When you run `Update-Database` the migrations are translated to SQL which is executed against your database. If you want to see the exact SQL being generated for a specific migration you can run `Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration SomeMigration -TargetMigration SomeOtherMigration`. This command does not modify the database, just generates and shows the SQL that would be applied in the real `Update-Database` execution.

More info about generating and running migrations can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_2).

Good luck!

**Update:** This answer applies to EF6. Be aware that things have changed a little after EF6, with EF Core. The basic concepts explained in this answer are the same, but the Package Manager Console commands have changed, and also the way EF deals with database context snapshots and migrations.

Comment: Thanks so much for your insights. I didnt delete my database. I tried deleting just the 'initial' file from the Migrations folder, not the whole folder. Then i did 'Add-Migration initial' and 'Update-Database'. It worked now!

Comment: Sorry for imposing, but i have a question regarding Code-first. Could you please have a look at it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42048555/is-there-any-way-i-can-just-create-a-table-in-sql-server-and-then-update-the-mig) for me?

Comment: Could you please have a look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42882670/project-models-tablenamethe-field-pvid-must-be-a-string-or-array-type-with-a-ma)? I would appreciate it much

Comment: Hi I've followed your way its working but when I deploy my code into azure it wont work again, saying the there is the object already exist. is there any other way I can check? thanks

Comment: @Dev I've used this approach with success with databases deployed to Azure, so this shouldn't be the problem. There are several variables that can cause the error. Are you using EF6, or a later version? Which version of .NET? Which exact error are you getting? When do you get this error, when executing the migrations on deploy, when trying to execute them from package manager console? Which database initialization strategy you use? I would recommend you to create a separate question providing more details.

Comment: Thanks @Diana I've managed to get it resolved by regenerating the Migration files , remove the changes in snapshot file, publish it, then readd the migration files, include the changes in snapshot file. I am using EF core. Cheers

Comment: @Dev glad you fixed it 