# Add-Migration error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, ef-code-first

I'm using code-first concept and just tried adding a new class to the Models folder in hope to create a new table in SQL server database. i've added

```
Public Overridable Property Diagnosis As DbSet(Of Diagnosis)
```

in the DBContext.vb.

Then in the package manager console, i entered Add-Migration Diagnosis. But below error comes out. Why is this? Can anyone help me out please?

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Full error in Package Manager Console:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.UI.ParseChildrenAttribute.GetHashCode()
   at System.Collections.Generic.ObjectEqualityComparer`1.GetHashCode(T obj)
   at System.Linq.Set`1.InternalGetHashCode(TElement value)
   at System.Linq.Set`1.Find(TElement value, Boolean add)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ExceptIterator>d__72`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.AttributeProvider.<GetAttributes>b__3(PropertyInfo pi)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.PropertyAttributeConfigurationConvention`1.<.ctor>b__0(ConventionTypeConfiguration ec)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.TypeConvention.ApplyCore(Type memberInfo, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.TypeConventionBase.Apply(Type memberInfo, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ConventionsConfiguration.ApplyModelConfiguration(Type type, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.Convention.ApplyModelConfiguration(Type type, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ConventionsConfiguration.ApplyModelConfiguration(Type type, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapComplexType(Type type, Boolean discoverNested)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.PropertyMapper.MapPrimitiveOrComplexOrEnumProperty(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, Func`1 structuralTypeConfiguration, Boolean discoverComplexTypes)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.PropertyMapper.MapIfNotNavigationProperty(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, EntityType entityType, Func`1 entityTypeConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.<>c__DisplayClass14.<MapEntityType>b__e(PropertyMapper m, PropertyInfo p)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapStructuralElements[TStructuralTypeConfiguration](Type type, ICollection`1 annotations, Action`2 propertyMappingAction, Func`1 structuralTypeConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.NavigationPropertyMapper.Map(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, EntityType entityType, Func`1 entityTypeConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.MapTypes(EdmModel model)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ModelBeingInitialized()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext context, XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetModel>b__0(XmlWriter w)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1 writeXml)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Scaffold(String migrationName, String language, String rootNamespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name, Boolean force, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I don't know if this is relevant or not, but in my web.config, there is a Default Connection that is already pre-set when i first created my project. When i first did Enable-Migrations i had to specify which connection it was. I've removed that line but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you been able to succesfully build your solution before trying the command? Also.. make sure that you are firring the command in your package manager console against the correct Project in which Entity Gramework is installed.

Comment: @Derek 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped. I've tried the add-migration in package manager console after build solution, but still same error. By 'against the correct Project', is choosing my project name in the Default Project dropdown right?

Comment: I dont know how your solution is broken up, but if you have multiple projects, youneed to make sure the package manager console is targeting the project with entity framework installed.

Comment: Please read [mcve]  and include relevant code and what line the error occurs on. Cheers.

Comment: @DavidWilson I've edited my question and added the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously when i did the add-migration, it didn't work because i simply created a class and added declaration of the respective strings, integer, etc. as variables like this:

```
Public Property id As String
```

Now it suddenly popped into my mind that i had to give a more elaborate description on each of the variables such as below:

```
<Key>
<StringLength(20)>
Public Property id As String
```

Now it works =')