# NullReferenceException during Entity Framework Core Add-Migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, console-application

I'm trying to test EF Core in my console application. My project structure is like

```
Project_name
 - Data Folder
   - AppDbContext.cs
 - Models Folder
   - Person.cs
   - Student.cs
   - Lecturer.cs
   .... etc
 
 - Program.cs
```

In my `AppDbContext.cs` I have configured like

```
    public class AppDbContext: DbContext
    {
    /*  public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options): base(options)
        {}*/

        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        
        public DbSet<Lecturer> Lecturers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Course> Coures { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<LecturerCourse> lecturerCourses{ get; set; }
        public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CourseNotice> courseNotices { get; set; }


        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.UseSqlServer(@"Server = (localdb)\\mssqllocaldb; Database = efcore_consoleApp; Trusted_Connection = True; MultipleActiveResultSets = true;");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            // Customize Course and AppUser relationship using FluentApi
            builder.Entity<LecturerCourse>()
                .HasKey(ca => new { ca.CourseId, ca.LecturerId });

            builder.Entity<LecturerCourse>()
                .HasOne(cu => cu.Course)
                .WithMany(c => c.LecturerCourses)
                .HasForeignKey(cu => cu.CourseId);

            builder.Entity<LecturerCourse>()
                .HasOne(cu => cu.Lecturer)
                .WithMany(u => u.LecturerCourses)
                .HasForeignKey(cu => cu.LecturerId);

            builder.Entity<Enrollment>()
                .HasKey(e => new { e.CourseId, e.StudentId });

            builder.Entity<Enrollment>()
                .HasOne(c => c.Course)
                .WithMany(e => e.Enrollments)
                .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.CourseId);

            builder.Entity<Enrollment>()
                .HasOne(s => s.Student)
                .WithMany(e => e.Enrollments)
                .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.StudentId);
        }

    }
```

I've installed some needed packages such

```
- EntityFrameworkCore(5.0.8)
- EntityFrameworkCoreDesign(5.0.8)
- EntityFrameworkCoreSqlServer(5.0.8)
- EntityFrameworkCoreTools(5.0.8)
```

When I try adding migration `Add-Migration ...`, the error such `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` occurred with stack trace like

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.SetOrAddForeignKey(ForeignKey foreignKey, InternalEntityTypeBuilder principalEntityTypeBuilder, IReadOnlyList`1 dependentProperties, Key principalKey, String propertyBaseName, Nullable`1 isRequired, Nullable`1 configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.CreateForeignKey(InternalEntityTypeBuilder principalEntityTypeBuilder, IReadOnlyList`1 dependentProperties, Key principalKey, String propertyBaseName, Nullable`1 required, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.HasRelationship(EntityType targetEntityType, Nullable`1 navigationToTarget, Nullable`1 inverseNavigation, Nullable`1 setTargetAsPrincipal, ConfigurationSource configurationSource, Nullable`1 required)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.HasRelationship(EntityType targetEntityType, MemberInfo navigationMember, ConfigurationSource configurationSource, Nullable`1 targetIsPrincipal)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder.HasOneBuilder(MemberIdentity navigationId, EntityType relatedEntityType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder`1.HasOne[TRelatedEntity](Expression`1 navigationExpression)
   at efcore_consoleApp.Data.AppDbContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) in C:\Users\PC_1\source\repos\efcore_consoleApp\efcore_consoleApp\AppDbContext.cs:line 44
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelCustomizer.Customize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_3(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
```

I'm new to EF Core and .NET development, so hope can get help!

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42362172/add-migration-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object

Comment: Stack trace says there's an error here: AppDbContext.cs:line 44.

Comment: According to the stacktrace the crash happens when the foreign keys defined in `OnModelCreating()` are analyzed. Try and remove as many `builder.Entity<T>()...` calls as possible so that the exception still happens. This should help to identify the involved model classes. Then show us those models, please.

Comment: @RoarS. Thank you for the mention! I've read through a stacktrace but didn't figure out that the problem was in the `line 44`. So as I defined above there is class `Person` which is `base class` of 2 other classes `Student` and `Lecturer`.  But in the `Person` class I don't use `primary key`  and defined it as `Keyless` (actually I don't want to use according to app logic that I want to be). After I tried removing `Person`, and the error is go away as well. Thank you again!

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride as I said I'm new to EF Core so those configurations are what I refered from other docs that help me configured the relationships between tables using `join table`. I've didn't removed any `builder.Entity<T>()` in `OnModelCreating()` but just removed `Person` class in `Models` folder and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

After got the mention that the problem probably in the `line 44` by looking through the stacktrace. I've checked the original code again and it was like in the `Models` folder I had have

```
[Keyless]
public class Person {
  // some general properties of person 
}

public class Lecturer: Person {
  public string Id { get; set; }

  // some properties that derived from `Person` 
}

public class Student: Person {
  public string Id { get; set; }

  // some properties that derived from `Person` 
}
```

After tried removing `Person` class

```
public class Lecturer {
  public string Id { get; set; }

  // some properties
}

public class Student {
  public string Id { get; set; }

  // some properties 
}
```

And now it worked. Tobe honest I still don't know what caused the problem exactly. Love to see someone experienced with that could give some explanation.

Comment: `public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }` in combination with `[Keyless]` on class Person is the issue. EF needs a primary key.